# User management using sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I need to make a basic user management system for my application using Sinatra but I'm not sure how I should think about it.

It needs to:

- Register User
- Login User

How should I think about it? This shouldn't be hard, I'm just very new to all this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you able to use [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/)?  It's got built-in admin with every app you create.  Watch the [video](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/blog-tutorial#screencast).

Comment: `padrino g admin` is all you need to do to get an admin resource up and running - and it's all built on top of sinatra

Comment: didn't know about padrino, very nice. However, I really need to make a custom solution, at least to be able to understand how it works.

Comment: Sinatra FAQ shows you how to do [HTTP authentication](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#auth) - You also have the [sinatra-authentication gem](http://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication) which looks ok - If you are looking to build one from scratch you might be able to learn something by studying the codes from the gem and see if you can come up with something that works for you - Also, the [sinatra mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/sinatrarb/search?group=sinatrarb&q=authentication&qt_g=Search+this+group) has a lot of useful advice regarding authentication - good luck

Comment: thanks for padrino, but for small projects sinatra is the best match, it is sad to hear about non-implemented user management. Thanks.